# Input to display datepicker in Swift - assigning to property error

Tags: swift, datepicker

```
Swift v 2
```

Just updated to `El Capitan` and of course `Xcode` and `swift` was included in the package.  I then created a new project with a `datePicker` and been since having an error.  I want to display a `datePicker` when the user taps the input view.  This is how my code looks so far:

```
@IBAction func addDate(var sender: AnyObject) {
        var datePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
        sender.inputView = datePickerView // This gives an error
        datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleDatePicker:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    }

    func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
        textfieldjobdate.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
    }
```

It gives me an error of ~`Cannot assign to property: 'sender' is immutable`, and not really sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Facing this issue as well, but I found out that instead of passing in `AnyObject`, use the native object instead.

E.g,
Replace this:

```
@IBAction func addDate(var sender: AnyObject) {...}
```

With this:

```
@IBAction func addDate(var sender: UITextField) {...}
```